# Pasting constantly updating xpath into google sheets

Tags: xpath, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm pretty fresh and trying to paste certain xpath from a website into sheets.

Url: "https://www.btcmarkets.net/"

Xpath: (from chrome copy xpath function) : `//*[@id="LastPriceAUDBTC"]`

I keep getting

> formula parse error

I have managed to get the table headings on with:

```
Xpath: "//tr"
```

but not the information within
Is this even possible?

### I know the google finance add-ons but I am analyzing the difference in prices of different exchanges.

QUERY #2

I would also like to

```
=importxml("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=CAD","//*[@id="ucc-container"]/span[2]/span[2]")
```

Should I be using =importDATA and shaving off what I don't want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes around the entire xpath but single quotes around the class name/id name/attribute name:

`"//*[@id='LastPriceAUDBTC']"`

And

`=importxml("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=CAD","//*[@id='ucc-container']/span[2]/span[2]")`